# request value de um checkbox em laravel

Tags: laravel

Preciso pegar o value desse checkbox mas nada esta dando certo.

```
@foreach ($options->getGenresEventos() as $agenda)
 <input type="checkbox" name="cat" id="cat" class="checkbox" value="{{strtolower($agenda)}}" data-bind="checked: params.genres"/> {{ $agenda }}<br><br>
@endforeach
```

fiz assim

```
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="@if(Input::get('genre')){{Input::get('genre')}} @else {{Request::('cat')}} @endif" />
```

agradeço qualquer ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Basta definir o checkbox no HTML.

Assim com HTML puro

```
<input type="checkbox" name="status" value="1">
```

e assim com o laravel collective

```
{!! Form::checkbox('status') !!}
```

Caso o checkbox não esteja selecionado ele não irá mandar para o controller via o request. então você pode verificar no controller dessa forma:

```
$dataForm = $request->all();

$dataForm['status'] = (!isset($dataForm['status']))? 0 : 1;
```